# char * and char [] in strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    char  str[] ="asdfasdf";
    char *s;
     strcpy(s,str);
     printf("%s",s);
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Am I messing up with char* and char[]?

Comment: just allocate memory to your pointer and then copy http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: Note that you should normally end format strings with a newline.

Comment: Perhaps start from reading the actual documentation for the strcpy function. It places certain requirements on its arguments. Does your program meet them?

Comment: I think it's a problem about the difference between pointer and array.

Comment: char * is pointer and char[] is array of chars

Comment: The pointer s does not point to a valid memory location. Either use malloc to allocate memory or use static memory. The strcpy would not allocate the memory for you. You need to do that.

Answer (score 5):

You never set `s` to a value, so you're invoking undefined behavior.
Perhaps `s = strdup(str);` is better in your case?

`strcpy` doesn't allocate space for your copy - it assumes you've already done that. `strdup` allocates memory for you. As Jonathan Leffler points out in the comment - if you don't want to use dynamic memory allocation, you just need a big enough "chunk" to copy the string into.

In your case, `char *` and `char[]` types can be used interchangeably, it's just that your pointer is not set to anything valid (it could be set to anything), but your code assumes it is valid.

Comment: Or: `char buffer[32]; char *str = buffer;` to avoid dynamic memory allocation which the OP may not have encountered yet.

Comment: What are the cases where char* and char[] cant be used interchangeably?

Comment: @bulbasaur You try to make the pedants happy and then you get a pedant going the other way ;-) When your char[] is not null terminated. `char a[3]; a[0] = 'A'; a[1]='B'; a[2]='C'` or when your char[] is really just numbers so 0 is valid (but would cause "weirdness" when a C string is expected. key being that `strcpy` expects it's char* arg to be 0 terminated string and OPs code gives it one.

Comment: `it's just that your pointer is not set to anything,`... is it really? I mean, it's obviously set to something, which is just not _valid_,maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`char *s;` in only a character pointer and currently does not point anywhere meaningful.

1. You can point `s` to `str`, and then both will point to the **same array in memory**.
2. You can create an empty character array `char s[16]`, where you can copy the array into. In this case, `s` and `str` will be two independent arrays, and will live in different memory address in the stack.
3. Allocate some memory to copy the string into by using `malloc` or `strdup`. Allocating memory is like taking out a loan. We need to give it back at the end of our program. Make sure to `free` the pointer once done using it. In this case, the two arrays live in different memory addresses, the first in the stack and second in the heap.